# ConnectionPool ActiveRecord questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, connection-pooling

I'm building an advanced RoR application with several instances of database connections running concurrently. However I'm still looking for answers for the following,

1. Does the connection handler automatically add a connection into the pool once its established? Like the following way,

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(spec)
   ```
2. When would it disconnect the active connection if there's no activity for a while? Or should it be manually disconnected.
3. Are there any other alternatives to disconnecting the database connection like the following,

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection(connection_object)
   ```
4. How can I increase the pool size which could be for different database adapters.

Looking forward to some tips.